# Xcode understanding how to analyze the call stack

Tags: xcode, debugging, callstack

I am using Xcode 4.3.1 and I don't quite understand how to use the console to get through the call stack. In my code I have multiple lines calling a particular action and inside this action there is an assertion that fails. From the output I can see only the assertion failure message and the addresses of the object calling the call stack (at least that's what I'm guessing they are). But I am not able to navigate through and see from which line of code of my class the action causing the assertion was called (a bit like what you can do analyzing the stack trace from Eclipse). Is there some relevant tutorial that explains this?

This is the action I am calling from multiple lines of my class:

```
   [[CCActionManager sharedManager] addAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeAction, nil] target:source paused:NO];
```

I understand that it throws the assertion but I am not able to understand from the console output which lines that calls this method causes this.

Here is my console output:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[CCActionManager addAction:target:paused:], /Users/user/Desktop/SourceCode - Backups/MyApp/MyApp/libs/cocos2d/CCActionManager.m:162
2012-06-21 12:40:54.761 MyApp[4148:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument target must be non-nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x338e08bf 0x303d41e5 0x338e07b9 0x311273b3 0xdc3b 0x5fbe5 0x66d2b 0x338e3814 0x3383e7e1 0x1afbb 0x1c39b 0x1981f 0x3383a435 0x435a7 0x43277 0x44aed 0x3128550f 0x31284f01 0x3126b4ed 0x3126ad2d 0x37fa9df3 0x338b4553 0x338b44f5 0x338b3343 0x338364dd 0x338363a5 0x37fa8fcd 0x31299743 0x58b9b 0x20e4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a technical note about this - [TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html). Particularly the section on symbolicating crash reports.

With the .dSYM file of the application you can turn the stack addresses (those hexadecimal numbers) into the calls from the source in a far more readable format.

Comment: Thanks..  I read the note and then searched for Sumbolication software to read the .dSYM file and found a good explanation on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832900/how-to-manually-symbolicate-ios-crash-to-view-crash-logs/8648232#8648232 I will try now but in the meanwhile I accept the answer as I think replies to my question. Thanks!