# reading crash logs itunes after app update

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I'v released an update to my app in AppStore, it got accepted pretty quick. Yet, it crashes right after an update. If installed on clean device it works, yet crashes if older version was present... I guess I messed up something and I'm trying to figure out what. I get crash reports from itunes connect, yet they do not tell me quite much. In other crash logs which I'v seen on stackoverflow questions there is Class name, method name and line of crash. While all my crash reports contain only bytes which give me zero information where and what is wrong.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                     0x3231b3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x3a01695e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                     0x32266ef4 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 160
3   kodinisRaktas                      0x000b939a 0x0009f000 + 107418
4   kodinisRaktas                      0x000b9282 0x0009f000 + 107138
5   kodinisRaktas                      0x000a2434 0x0009f000 + 13364
6   UIKit                              0x34149574 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
7   UIKit                              0x3419e1f2 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
8   UIKit                              0x3419e138 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
9   UIKit                              0x3419e01c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
10  UIKit                              0x3419df48 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 268
11  UIKit                              0x3419d694 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
12  UIKit                              0x3419d57c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
13  UIKit                              0x3416e55c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 176
14  UIKit                              0x3412d8c2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
15  QuartzCore                         0x33ed950e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
16  QuartzCore                         0x33ed90b0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
17  QuartzCore                         0x33f07eca -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 138
18  UIKit                              0x341d70dc -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 204
19  UIKit                              0x341d62c6 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3598
20  UIKit                              0x341d54aa -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
21  UIKit                              0x341d5434 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 64
22  UIKit                              0x3430acb4 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke_0 + 100
23  UIKit                              0x3419367e -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 214
24  UIKit                              0x341933c2 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 690
25  UIKit                              0x34192d2a -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 150
26  UIKit                              0x34189e86 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 366
27  UIKit                              0x341d4ef2 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 658
28  kodinisRaktas                      0x000a1bd4 0x0009f000 + 11220
29  kodinisRaktas                      0x000a18f6 0x0009f000 + 10486
30  UIKit                              0x3418aa9c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
31  UIKit                              0x3418a620 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
32  UIKit                              0x3418282e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
33  UIKit                              0x3412ad1a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
34  UIKit                              0x3412a7a8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
35  UIKit                              0x3412a1ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
36  GraphicsServices                   0x35e425f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
37  GraphicsServices                   0x35e42222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
38  CoreFoundation                     0x322f03e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
39  CoreFoundation                     0x322f0386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
40  CoreFoundation                     0x322ef20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
41  CoreFoundation                     0x32262238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
42  CoreFoundation                     0x322620c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
43  UIKit                              0x34181468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
44  UIKit                              0x3417e2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
45  kodinisRaktas                      0x000a0d96 0x0009f000 + 7574
46  kodinisRaktas                      0x000a0d4c 0x0009f000 + 7500
```

I can't reproduce the crash on my own device, so this is all I got to determine the crash source. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you install the old version, run it, and then install the current version through Xcode?

Comment: Sadly, but no. I do not have the previous version archived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should symbolicate the crash log by opening it in Xcode and clicking Re-symbolicate. If this doesn't work you can do something like this [How to Manually Symbolicate iOS Crash to View Crash Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832900/how-to-manually-symbolicate-ios-crash-to-view-crash-logs)

Comment: First you have to open the Organizer (Window -> Organizer), then you have to go to the Devices tab and then you can eventually drag and drop the .crash file to the "Library" tab, under the voice "Device logs"

Comment: Thanks, found it and now got the crash lines !