# Release version of my xamarin forms iOS app is crashing on application launch

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, xamarin.ios

I have created a Xamarin Forms PCL app and have uploaded it to Itunes connect. They replied that it crashes on launch.

I have also done 7+ builds to testflight testing this myself and it is indeed an issue. I've added hockeyapp but the app does't even get to the stage where i can send the crash log back to myself.

Here is the crash log. Its not symbolicated as it is apples log file. I cannot get any crash logs on my own device for this application?? i'm so confused.

```
     "app_name":"FatForWeightLossApp.iOS","timestamp":"2016-11-07 10:06:11.37 -0800","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"10e200f4-8f87-3f49-bf8a-b980774cfba9","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.0","bundleID":"com.FatForWeightLoss","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)","incident_id":"70BB9B87-9857-4A7D-9FE8-8E80CA22AC5D","name":"FatForWeightLossApp.iOS"
 Incident Identifier: 70BB9B87-9857-4A7D-9FE8-8E80CA22AC5D
 CrashReporter Key:   6079b68e9b231d52a24bc0ce1c55aa975b16774c
 Hardware Model:      xxx
 Process:             FatForWeightLossApp.iOS [418]
 Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E5C99B9B-DF91-4A77-BA38-E5E556630AA4/FatForWeightLossApp.iOS.app/FatForWeightLossApp.iOS
 Identifier:          com.FatForWeightLoss
 Version:             1.0 (1.0)
 Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
 Role:                Foreground
 Parent Process:      launchd [1]
 Coalition:           com.FatForWeightLoss [408]


 Date/Time:           2016-11-07 10:06:11.3053 -0800
 Launch Time:         2016-11-07 10:06:10.0050 -0800
 OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
 Report Version:      104

 Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
 Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
 Triggered by Thread:  0

 Application Specific Information:
 abort() called

 Filtered syslog:
 None found

 Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826ba014 0x18269b000 + 126996
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182782450 0x18277d000 + 21584
 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018262e3e0 0x1825cb000 + 406496
 3   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010010b680 0x1000d8000 + 210560
 4   libsystem_platform.dylib       0x000000018277c348 0x182776000 + 25416
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182782450 0x18277d000 + 21584
 6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018262e3e0 0x1825cb000 + 406496
 7   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001f396c 0x1000d8000 + 1161580
 8   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010010bdb8 0x1000d8000 + 212408
 9   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010010b314 0x1000d8000 + 209684
 10  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010010a3f4 0x1000d8000 + 205812
 11  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100102f18 0x1000d8000 + 175896
 12  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010054db78 0x1000d8000 + 4676472
 13  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001003838ec 0x1000d8000 + 2799852
 14  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100382410 0x1000d8000 + 2794512
 15  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010021f7c8 0x1000d8000 + 1341384
 16  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100242d44 0x1000d8000 + 1486148
 17  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010051aad4 0x1000d8000 + 4467412
 18  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100118314 0x1000d8000 + 262932
 19  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100174a30 0x1000d8000 + 641584
 20  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010017498c 0x1000d8000 + 641420
 21  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000101027ec4 0x1000d8000 + 16056004
 22  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001010285bc 0x1000d8000 + 16057788
 23  Foundation                     0x00000001841d365c 0x1840c9000 + 1091164
 24  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183698278 0x1835bb000 + 905848
 25  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183697b50 0x1835bb000 + 904016
 26  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001836957c0 0x1835bb000 + 894912
 27  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001835c4048 0x1835bb000 + 36936
 28  GraphicsServices               0x000000018504a198 0x18503e000 + 49560
 29  UIKit                          0x00000001895a92fc 0x18952e000 + 504572
 30  UIKit                          0x00000001895a4034 0x18952e000 + 483380
 31  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100288a84 0x1000d8000 + 1772164
 32  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010020c0bc 0x1000d8000 + 1261756
 33  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010020c07c 0x1000d8000 + 1261692
 34  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001f8064 0x1000d8000 + 1179748
 35  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010051aad4 0x1000d8000 + 4467412
 36  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100118314 0x1000d8000 + 262932
 37  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100174a30 0x1000d8000 + 641584
 38  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100176a54 0x1000d8000 + 649812
 39  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100176670 0x1000d8000 + 648816
 40  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100102738 0x1000d8000 + 173880
 41  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001f79ac 0x1000d8000 + 1178028
 42  FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000101045814 0x1000d8000 + 16177172
 43  libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001825a85b8 0x1825a4000 + 17848

 Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826baa88 0x18269b000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277e35c 0x18277d000 + 4956
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277dda4 0x18277d000 + 3492

 Thread 2:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826baa88 0x18269b000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277e178 0x18277d000 + 4472
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277dda4 0x18277d000 + 3492

 Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826baa88 0x18269b000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277e35c 0x18277d000 + 4956
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277dda4 0x18277d000 + 3492

 Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826b9e1c 0x18269b000 + 126492
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277f9c0 0x18277d000 + 10688
 2   libc++.1.dylib                 0x00000001820a93ec 0x1820a2000 + 29676
 3   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000187e6f548 0x187598000 + 9270600
 4   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000187e6f4bc 0x187598000 + 9270460
 5   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000187e6f39c 0x187598000 + 9270172
 6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000187e6f64c 0x187598000 + 9270860
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 5 name:  WebThread
 Thread 5:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018269c16c 0x18269b000 + 4460
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018269bfdc 0x18269b000 + 4060
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183697cec 0x1835bb000 + 904428
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183695908 0x1835bb000 + 895240
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001835c4048 0x1835bb000 + 36936
 5   WebCore                        0x000000018816d45c 0x188107000 + 418908
 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 6 name:  SGen worker
 Thread 6:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826b9e1c 0x18269b000 + 126492
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277f9c0 0x18277d000 + 10688
 2   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001c7630 0x1000d8000 + 980528
 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 7 name:  Finalizer
 Thread 7:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018269c1a8 0x18269b000 + 4520
 1   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100143bb0 0x1000d8000 + 441264
 2   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010019c8d8 0x1000d8000 + 805080
 3   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001e51a4 0x1000d8000 + 1102244
 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 8 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
 Thread 8:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018269c16c 0x18269b000 + 4460
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018269bfdc 0x18269b000 + 4060
 2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183697cec 0x1835bb000 + 904428
 3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183695908 0x1835bb000 + 895240
 4   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001835c4048 0x1835bb000 + 36936
 5   Foundation                     0x00000001840d5a8c 0x1840c9000 + 51852
 6   Foundation                     0x00000001840f657c 0x1840c9000 + 185724
 7   UIKit                          0x0000000189f1ea2c 0x18952e000 + 10422828
 8   Foundation                     0x00000001841d347c 0x1840c9000 + 1090684
 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 9 name:  tid_760f
 Thread 9:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826b9e1c 0x18269b000 + 126492
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277f9c0 0x18277d000 + 10688
 2   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001e8ef8 0x1000d8000 + 1117944
 3   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001971d4 0x1000d8000 + 782804
 4   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010019c8d8 0x1000d8000 + 805080
 5   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001e51a4 0x1000d8000 + 1102244
 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 10 name:  Threadpool worker
 Thread 10:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826b9e1c 0x18269b000 + 126492
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277f9c0 0x18277d000 + 10688
 2   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100197bfc 0x1000d8000 + 785404
 3   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010019c8d8 0x1000d8000 + 805080
 4   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001e51a4 0x1000d8000 + 1102244
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 11 name:  Threadpool worker
 Thread 11:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001826b9e1c 0x18269b000 + 126492
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277f9c0 0x18277d000 + 10688
 2   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x0000000100197bfc 0x1000d8000 + 785404
 3   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x000000010019c8d8 0x1000d8000 + 805080
 4   FatForWeightLossApp.iOS        0x00000001001e51a4 0x1000d8000 + 1102244
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780850 0x18277d000 + 14416
 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182780760 0x18277d000 + 14176
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018277ddac 0x18277d000 + 3500

 Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
     x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000000000001b
     x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016fd23360   x6: 0x0000000000000039   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
     x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000018277c314  x11: 0x0000000101544000
    x12: 0xffffffffffffc000  x13: 0x0000000101540000  x14: 0x0000000080002000  x15: 0x0000000080000000
    x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001835e35a0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
    x20: 0x00000001a7f37c40  x21: 0x00000001010ca244  x22: 0x00000001010ca2a1  x23: 0x0cdc9c68cc2a00d2
    x24: 0x000000016fd23748  x25: 0x00000001010ca254  x26: 0x0000000101ada748  x27: 0x0000000104422c50
    x28: 0x0000000101500f00   fp: 0x000000016fd236e0   lr: 0x0000000182782450
     sp: 0x000000016fd236c0   pc: 0x00000001826ba014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Have you tried a build in release mode to a real device. sometimes these errors are caused by the linker. Also, you should be able to manually symbolic the log file if you still have the dsym for that version of the app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832900/how-to-manually-symbolicate-ios-crash-to-view-crash-logs

Comment: I have "Link SDK Assemblies Only" set in the release build section. I will try "Don't Link" and see if that changes anything. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply because I had selected "release" in the build config instead of "App Store". App would start but instantly crash. Linker was fine with SDK only.